# VBscript to zip log files with 7zip

Tags: vbscript, zip

Would like someone to take a look at my script and tell me where I am messing up.

It is a script to zip log files and then I would like to move them into a new folder that is going to be shared over a network. Right now I am just trying to get the part where it zips up the files using 7zip correctly.

I am very new to VB (like 2 days) so having some syntax problems I think.

Script is found below, thank you in advance for all advice and help

```
Option Explicit

WScript.Echo "Press to start zipping log files."

Dim objFile, objPath, objFolder, Command, PathLogs, RetVal
Dim objFSO: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

PathLogs = "C:\Testscripts\testfolder\" 'This path just has some test logs
```

' Loop through the logs and zip and move each file (if required, you could just move files with an '.log' extension)

```
Set objPath = objFSO.GetFolder(PathLogs)
For Each objFile In objPath.Files
If (LCase(objfso.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "log") Then
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
    ' zip and move files
    'Command = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" -m -ex """ & PathLogs &     \objFile.Name objfso.GetBaseName(objFile) & "*.zip"" """ & PathLogs & objFile.Name & """"
     Command = ""C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" a -m -ex " & PathLogs & "" & objFile.Name & ".zip " & PathLogs & "" & objFile.Name & "
        WScript.Echo "Command: " & Command
RetVal = objShell.Run(Command,0,true)

End If

Next

WScript.Echo "Zip Successful."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your quotes wrong. To use a quote inside a string, you have to duplicate the quote.

```
Command = """C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe"" a -m -ex " _ 'this is the first part of the string
          & PathLogs & objFile.Name & ".zip " & PathLogs & objFile.Name
```

If your Logfile or PathLogs can contain spaces they must be quoted as well.

Comment: That fixed my error but I am still having a problem with it not actually zipping the files. It will go through and say that the script is completed and all of the echo's will go through but it doesn't actually zip the log files that it is finding. any suggestions?

Comment: At least my 7z.exe does not understand -m and -ex. Without it, the script works. It helps to print the command and execute it from the command line manually or evaluate the return code of objShell.Run.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That fixed the problem with the zipping. My issue now is that I am trying to get all of the log files to go into 1 zipped file. The way it currently is with the changes the files are being zipped into two seperate zips. Thank you for all of your help so far. Learning this on the fly is a bit more difficult than I thought it would be.

Comment: Just use always the same name for the zip (replace the first objFile.Name by the name of your zipfile)

Comment: So if I was trying to get the zipped files to be named something like "localhost.zip" I could replace the first objFile.name with something like %computername%.zip?

Comment: It look like it would work. The environment variable must be inside the string: PathLogs & "%computername%.zip"

Comment: Ah, yea that works perfectly. You've been an amazing help man.

Comment: I've added in for the files to be moved once they have been zipped. Is there a simple way to tell the script to delete the original log files once they have been zipped?

Comment: Should be objFSO.DeleteFile(  PathLogs & objFile.Name). But you should at least check the return code of the Run method, that there was no error in zipping the file.

Comment: How to 7zip the whole folder instead of files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710114/vbscript-how-to-7zip-a-folder-instead-of-file